# Can BuildBundlerMinifier update bundles ON FILE SAVE in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: bundler, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm considering switching for Visual Studio 17 to JetBrains Rider and so far really like it. However, all the docs I can find for JetBrains Rider suggest that the bundle is rebundled on build. In Visual Studio and on the BuildBundlerMinifier the rebuilding occurs when a source file is updated. Can it be done in Rider?

EDIT: BuildBundlerMinifier is a popular (most popular?) bundler/minifier nuget package by Mads Kristensen: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is `BuildBundlerMinifier`, but if you can run it as a console tool, you can setup Rider to do that for you.

There are two ways you can do that:

1. Go to `File | Settings | Tools | Custom Tools` and specify your tool there. It suitable for situations when the bundle file is marked in csproj with MsBuild `CustomTool` property. Also you can use custom tools specifying a file's extension.
2. Go to `File | Settings | Tools | External Tools` and specify an external tool using different macros. But I have to warn you - this part of Rider inherited from IDEA so some macro do not work as expected.

If none of these options work for you please fire an issue here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=Rider

But [please] describe the technology in details and attach a sample project/solution if possible. It helps us a lot to understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @xtmq. I updated the original post to link to BuildBundlerMinifier, which I think is in really wide use with VS, and will see if it can be configured using you methods.